# Skip x last lines when reading a text file

Tags: java, io

I read text data from big file line by line.
But I need to read just n-x lines(don't read last x lines) .

How can I do it without reading whole file more than 1 time?
(I read line and immediately process it, so i can't go back)

Comment: Read the file and delete the last x lines.

Comment: I can't modify the source file I also don't want to create a copy of it (>4gb)

Comment: Interesting problem, I vote it up. But I'm afraid you cannot do that easily if you don't know the total number of lines before processing them.

Comment: yes, I don't know the number of total lines

Comment: If you don't know the number of lines you can't do it without reading the whole file. If You process the line immediately seems like @Yoni's answer is the best solution.

Comment: He's not against reading the whole file, he's against reading the whole more than once (quite reasonable). And that is possible, yes Yoni and me have exactly the same (simple) solution.

Comment: I've provided example code implementing two solutions which are very different, though depending on the use case one of them will fit better than the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this post I'll provide you with two completely different approaches to solving your problem, and depending on your use case one of the solutions will fit better than the other.

**Alternative #1**

This method is memory efficient though quite complex, if you are going to skip a lot of contents this method is recommended since you only will store one line at a time in memory during processing.

The implementation of it in this post might not be **super** optimized, but the theory behind it stands clear.

You will start by reading the file backwards, searching for N number of line breaks. When you've successfully located where in the file you'd like to stop your processing later on you will jump back to the beginning of the file.

**Alternative #2**

This method is easy to comprehend and is very straight forward. During execution you will have N number of lines stored in memory, where N is the number of lines you'd like to skip in the end.

The lines will be stored in a FIFO container (*First In, First Out*). You'll append the last read line to your FIFO and then remove and process the first entry. This way you will always process lines at least N entries away from the end of your file.

---

---

## Alternative #1

This might sound odd but it's definitely doable and the way I'd recommend you to do it; start by reading the file **backwards**.

1. Seek to the end of the file
2. Read (and discard) bytes (towards the beginning of the file) until you've found `SKIP_N` line breaks
3. Save this position
4. Seek to the beginning of the file
5. Read (and process) lines until you've come down to the position you've stored away

---

### Example code:

The code below will strip off the last `42` lines from `/tmp/sample_file` and print the rest using the method described earlier in this post.

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.File;

import java.lang.Math;

public class Example {
  protected static final int SKIP_N = 42;

  public static void main (String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    File fileHandle            = new File ("/tmp/sample_file");
    RandomAccessFile rafHandle = new RandomAccessFile (fileHandle, "r");
    String s1                  = new String ();

    long currentOffset = 0;
    long endOffset     = findEndOffset (SKIP_N, rafHandle);

    rafHandle.seek (0);

    while ((s1 = rafHandle.readLine ()) != null) {
      ;   currentOffset += s1.length () + 1; // (s1 + "\n").length
      if (currentOffset >= endOffset)
        break;

      System.out.println (s1);
    }
  }

  protected static long findEndOffset (int skipNLines, RandomAccessFile rafHandle)
    throws Exception
  {
    long currentOffset = rafHandle.length ();
    long endOffset     =  0;
    int  foundLines    =  0;

    byte [] buffer      = new byte[
      1024 > rafHandle.length () ? (int) rafHandle.length () : 1024
    ];

    while (foundLines < skipNLines && currentOffset != 0) {
      currentOffset = Math.max (currentOffset - buffer.length, 0);

      rafHandle.seek      (currentOffset);
      rafHandle.readFully (buffer);

      for (int i = buffer.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
          ++foundLines;

          if (foundLines == skipNLines)
            endOffset = currentOffset + i - 1; // we want the end to be BEFORE the newline
        }
      }
    } 

    return endOffset;
  }
}
```

---

---

## Alternative #2

1. Read from your file line by line
2. On every successfully read line, insert the line at the back of your `LinkedList<String>`
3. If your `LinkedList<String>` contains more lines than you'd like to skip, remove the first entry and process it
4. Repeat until there are no more lines to be read

---

### Example code

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Example {
  protected static final int SKIP_N = 42; 

  public static void main (String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    String line;

    LinkedList<String> lli = new LinkedList<String> (); 

    FileInputStream   fis = new FileInputStream   ("/tmp/sample_file");
    DataInputStream   dis = new DataInputStream   (fis);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (dis);
    BufferedReader    bre = new BufferedReader    (isr);

    while ((line = bre.readLine ()) != null) {
      lli.addLast (line);

      if (lli.size () > SKIP_N) {
        System.out.println (lli.removeFirst ());
      }   
    }   

    dis.close (); 
  }
}
```

Comment: waiting for your code thanks! I didn't know you can read from file until stored position

Comment: @markiz Sorry it took so long, I'm still at work and got caught up doing other things. The sample solution got a bit messy, I apologize for that, kept running back and forth between my personal computer and a work related things.

Comment: @markiz Added further explanation of the theory used, I also wrote a different alternative solution using the theory discussed in other posts in this thread. Which of the solutions suits you better depends on the context.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a simple read-ahead logic.

Read `x` lines first and put them in a buffer. Then you can repeatedly read one line at a time, add it to the end of the buffer, and process the first line in the buffer. When you reach `EOF`, you have `x` unprocessed lines in the buffer.

**Update:** I noticed the comments on the question and my own answer, so just to clarify: my suggestion works when `n` is unknown. `x` should be known, of course. All you need to do is create a simple buffer, and then fill up the buffer with x lines, and then start your processing.

Regarding the implementation of the buffer, as long as we are talking about Java's built-in collections, a simple `LinkedList` is all you need. Since you'll be pulling one line out of the buffer for every line that you place in it, `ArrayList` won't perform well do to constant shifting of array indices. Generally speaking, an array-backed buffer would have to be circular to avoid bad performance.

Comment: You could put each line in a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: How could a PriorityQueue help ? He needs some kind of circular structure instead. Unfortunately, Java does not provide any :/

Comment: What's so circular about it? It's just a queue.

Answer (score 2):

Just read `x` lines ahead. That is have a queue of `x` lines.

Comment: what you are saying, I should create a n-size queue, fill it as I read file line by line. when queu is filled I process it iff it's not EOF?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Push on one one side, pop and process on the other while there are still lines to read.

Comment: I think you meant x lines ahead, not n

Comment: err, yes, I meant `n`, but it wasn't the OP's `n`, I'll change it to `x` to avoid confusion, thanks :)